# can anyone give a proof by definition: $11$ is prime in $ \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}] $

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

what i did is:
assume $\alpha  \notin (11),\beta\notin (11), \alpha\beta \in (11)\Rightarrow\exists \gamma, s.t.$  $ \alpha\beta = 11 \gamma$, $\Rightarrow N(\alpha)N(\beta) = 11^2N(\gamma)  $

then there are 2 cases
one case is $11|N(\alpha)$ and  $11|N(\beta)$
the other is $11^2|N(\alpha)$ or $11^2|N(\beta)$

my prof said both cases will lead to a contradiction, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Not to be a jerk about it, but 11 is not prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, though it is irreducible. Maybe you're trying to prove that $\langle 11 \rangle$ is a prime ideal?

Comment: @RobertSoupe:  The usual definition of prime $\pi$ in an integral domain is $\pi$ divides $\alpha\beta$ implies $\pi$ divides $\alpha$ or $\pi$ divides $\beta$. My answer below verifies that this is the case here. Of course $11$ is also irreducible, which is easier to prove and in general, and in particular in this domain, not equivalent to primality.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So then in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, 2, 3 and 7 are irreducible but not prime, 5 is composite, and 11 is prime *and* irreducible?

Comment: @RobertSoupe:  About $2,3,5,11$ yes. Other irreducible and not prime are $1+\sqrt{-5}$ and its conjugate. About $7$ I have not checked.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Well, there's $14 = (3 - \sqrt{-5})(3 + \sqrt{-5})$. I did look for multiples of 11 with a factorization of that form, though, as you can probably imagine, without success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We will show that if $11$ divides $\alpha\beta$ then $11$ divides $\alpha$ or $11$ divides $\beta$. Since $11$ is obviously not a unit  of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$,
by the definition of prime it follows that $11$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.

From the post, it is clear that you know that if $11$ divides $\alpha\beta$, then $11$ divides $N(\alpha)N(\beta)$ and therefore $11$ divides $N(\alpha)$ or $11$ divides $N(\beta)$.

Let $\alpha=s+t\sqrt{-5}$.  Then $N(\alpha)=s^2+5t^2$. Suppose that $11$ divides $s^2+5t^2$. We will show that $11$ divides $t$ (and therefore $11$ divides $s$).

Suppose that $s^2+5t^2=11k$, and $11$ does not divide $t$. Let $wt\equiv 1\pmod{11}$ (there is such a $w$ since $t$ has an inverse modulo $11$).

We get $(ws)^2\equiv -5\equiv 6\pmod{11}$. This is impossible, since $6$ is not a quadratic residue of $11$ (just try all squares up to $5^2$).

Since $11$ divides $t$ and $s$, it follows that $11$ divides $\alpha$.

If $11$ does not divide $N(\alpha)$, it must divide $N(\beta)$, and then we conclude in the same way that $11$ divides $\beta$.

Comment: Do you mean $s^2+5t^2$ instead of $x^2+5t^2$?

Comment: Can you give more details about the solution of the equations? I'm very alien to number theory thank you

Comment: @Hayden I think it should be